# Maximize an application on half of the screen on wayland

Tags: fedora, wayland, splitpane

I'd like to open gnome-terminal maximized on half of the screen. Just like when you are hitting the shortcut 'super+Left'. I am using a bash script anyway so a hacky solution is ok.

On X11 I could just add

```
$xdotool key 'super+Left'
```

to my start-up script but xdotool doesn't work anymore because I switched to Fedora 26 + wayland. I could also adjust the number of rows and columns of gnome-terminal but there remain some whitespace.

Any ideas are appreciated!